# How to fix NullpointerException error scala

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, akka

So when i receive message from rabbitmq i want to send it to actor, but when i'm trying to match message i'm getting nullpointerexception. As it appears trouble occurs when i'm matching "msg" and trying send it to actor. Without this part " msg match {
            case _ => drawer ! Drawer.Data(msg)
          }" All works. How to fix it?

```
import java.util.UUID

import Client.{GameBullet, GameTank}
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, ActorRef}
import com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP.BasicProperties
import com.rabbitmq.client.{AMQP, ConnectionFactory, DefaultConsumer, Envelope}
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.{read, write}



object MessageSender {

  case object Left

  case object Right

  case object Up

  case object Down

  case object StartGame

  case object MakeShot

  case object Start


}

case class Message(id:String,content:String)

class MessageSender(drawer:ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging{
 import  MessageSender._
  val factory = new ConnectionFactory()
  factory.setHost("localhost")
  val connection = factory.newConnection()
  val channel = connection.createChannel()
  val replyQueueName: String = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue
  val corrId = UUID.randomUUID().toString
  channel.queueBind(replyQueueName, "myDirect", replyQueueName)
  val props = new BasicProperties.Builder().correlationId(corrId).replyTo(replyQueueName).build()

  var currentId = 0
  var message = ""

  implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(ShortTypeHints(List(classOf[Message])))

  override def receive: Receive = {

    case StartGame =>
      message="startGame"
      var response: String = null
      var msg:String =""
      val code = pretty(render(Extraction.decompose(Message(currentId.toString,message))))
      println(code)
      channel.basicPublish("myDirect", "service", props, code.getBytes("UTF-8"))
      println(replyQueueName)
      println(corrId)
      while(response == null){
        val consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
          override def handleDelivery(consumerTag: String,
                                      envelope: Envelope,
                                      properties: AMQP.BasicProperties,
                                      body: Array[Byte]) {
            msg = new String(body, "UTF-8")
            println(properties.getCorrelationId)

           println(s"message is $msg")
            if(properties.getCorrelationId == corrId){
              response = new String(body, "UTF-8")
            }
          }
        }
        channel.basicConsume(replyQueueName, true, consumer)
      }

      currentId=response.toInt
      log.info(s"Session started [$currentId]")
     msg match {
        case _ => drawer ! Drawer.Data(msg)
      }
      self ! Start    
  }
}
```

Error:
[This i get when i try match msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSEZb.png)

Comment: It means that your `msg` is null at that point. You need to ensure that `msg` is not `null` for the `match` and handle the `null` possibility separately.

Answer (score 0):

According to the attached screenshot, the exception occurs on line 83 of this class.
The problem is therefore that the `drawer` member is null, so `drawer ! Drawer.Data(msg)` throws NPE.
I would guess that the initialization of the actor (using `props`) is done with a variable that is defined later in the same scope resulting with a "froward reference".

See my example in your other related question ([Scala Akka NullPointerException error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853920/scala-akka-nullpointerexception-error/51883690#51883690))